# Implementing RabbitMQ pub sub

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging, publish-subscribe, amqp

I am trying to incorporate RabbitMQ based pub sub for a specific programming scenario,

I have a Web API endpoint. When I get a `201` response from this service I want to send out emails.

I already have another API endpoint which I can call to send out email.

Where do I setup the mailer?

And how do I setup RabbitMQ to handle this scenario?
To clarify further, should this be a `fanout` exchange setup or not? And how are mails usually handled transient or persistent queues?

Comment: "Where do I setup the mailer?" --- as a separate worker. "And how do I setup RabbitMQ to handle this scenario?" --- this is not clear. Have you read rabitmq documentation?

Comment: @zerkms updated the Q with more specific clarification.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit further, you have a process that's hitting some endpoint, if that endpoint returns a 201, then you want to hit another endpoint so that it sends out the emails?

Comment: @TravisR Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a typical worker scenario where one side will queue up jobs/messages into a message queue (producer) and the other side will get the messages and process them (consumer/worker). In your case, the workers will get messages and send out an email (or hit your api endpoint that sends out emails). The workers typically run on separate machines so they can do work without affecting your application or api.

If you're using RabbitMQ, you should read the "Work Queues" tutorial to see how to set it up for your scenario: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

There are some hosted solutions specifically for this too that don't require any setup like [IronMQ](http://www.iron.io/mq) for a message queue. Or even a step further if you don't want to deal with worker servers, you can use [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/worker).